# Error while using antd components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

[image: This was the error when using these components]Am using antd components for ui design, while using these components some of the components works and others not.

Imported all of the components

import {
Table,
Typography,
Select,
Space,
Row,
Col,
Form,
Button,
Layout,
Tag,
Badge,
Title,
Content,
Divider,
Progress,
Text
} from "antd/lib";

---

```
<Row>
  <Col span={12} />
    <Col span={12} pull={5}></Col>
      <Layout>
        <Content style={{ padding: "30px 20px" }}>
          <div style={{ padding: 24, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
            <Title level={4}>Coverage Report</Title>
            <Divider />
             <Row justify="space-between">
               <Col span={6}></Col>
               <Col span={6}>
                 <Progress type="circle" percent={100} />
               </Col>
               <Col span={6} style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
                 <Text strong>
                   {data.length - selectedRowKeys.length} tests are available to test
                 </Text>
               </Col>
               <Col span={6}></Col>
             </Row>
           </div>
         </Content>
       </Layout>
     </Row>
```

No issue with Row, Col, and Layout components beacause i have already used these components before this code, the issue is with other components like Content, Title, Text and Progress.

Antd version - ^4.7.2
React - ^17.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you aren't importing Content, Title and Text correctly. Looking at docs for Title and Text it is part of Typography.

```js
const {Title, Text} = Typography;
const {Content} = Layout;
```